# How to suppress the browser top bar while using a BlackBerry BrowserSession

Tags: java, blackberry, browser

I am trying to create an app that will redirect to a certain webpage when run. I would like this app to be full screen with no title bar or browse bar. I am able to call a BrowseSession to bring up the proper website in the browser but it doesn't give me the desired feel.

Here is the code I am using for the BrowseSession:

```
BrowserSession browser = Browser.getDefaultSession();
browser.displayPage("http://www.stackoverflow.com");
```

I have looked into using a BrowseField for this but I find that it does not act in the same fashion as a regular BrowseSession. The device Back Button closes the app and I receive errors in my simulator when JavaScript code is being run. My code for this follows:

```
String baseURL = "http://www.stackoverflow.com";

BrowserFieldConfig config = new BrowserFieldConfig();
config.setProperty(BrowserFieldConfig.JAVASCRIPT_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);
BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField(config);
add(browserField);

browserField.requestContent(baseURL);
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to control the overall appearance of the browser programmatically, so you're stuck with the title bar and browse bar if you use `BrowserSession`.

And JavaScript is broken for `BrowserField` on some of the simulators, although I think it may work on all the actual devices (although I wouldn't be surprised if it didn't work).

The only thing I can suggest is handling and cancelling the ESC key (aka the back button) press, which should at least prevent the app from closing.

Comment: And a snarky solution: write your app for Android instead. :)

Comment: It would be ideal for the back button to actually go back to the previous page. Thoughts on that?

Comment: We have an android app we are trying to hit all platforms

Comment: `BrowserField` has a `back()` method that you can call when you handle the ESC key press. No guarantee that this works as expected, of course.

Comment: Regarding all platforms: RIM will probably either be dead in 6 months or switched to Android or Windows Phone. I say this as someone who just invested half of the last year on a BB app that is dying thanks to a lack of BB users.

Comment: @MusiGenesis: It's a different story in Canada.

Comment: @Jason: I thought ostriches were from Africa? :)